# Why does Ubuntu hangs and looks 1995ish before logout?

Tags: performance, themes, logout

Since 11.10 upgrade, logging out takes a while (it used to be much faster on the same computer)
I can't determine what's causing this, but for a few moments at logout, my system seems to "freeze", the opened windows switch to an ugly theme before it can complete the logout.
[image: Screen]
What's causing this ? Can I prevent it and thus fasten up shutdown/logout ?

Comment: Strange problems are sometimes fixed with a fresh install. A fresh install is also less likely to cause any problems.

Comment: I'm not going to do a fresh install for that... Reinstall is for windows users, isn't it ?

Comment: then enjoy it! :)

Comment: OT Trivia: that 1995-ish look is named 'redmond', the MS codename for that look.